# Is it possible to hide data-attributes visible when inspecting a page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, custom-data-attribute

I'm passing data through data-attributes but I don't want users to be able to inspect the page and see this data.

How could I hide this data from the user ?

What I currently have :

```
<li data-first="<%= somedata %>" data-second="<%= somedata %>" data-third="<%= somedata %>" class="someclass">
</li>

Which is displayed as :

<li data-first="datatohide" data-second="datatohide" data-third=" datatohide" class="someclass">
</li>
```

What I would like the user to see when inspecting :

```
<li class="someclass">
</li>

OR 

<li data-first="" data-second="" data-third="" class="someclass">
</li>
```

Comment: Don't think that it is possible. Why do you need this data? Maybe there is other way to solve your problem

Comment: No. If you do not want the user to see those data attributes, don't put them in the HTML and find a different way to do what the data attributes are supposed to signify. If you have alot of different data attributes on your HTML nodes, it's usually a sign of using HTML as your data model instead of having HTML show a view of your data model. ( basic MVC )

Comment: @Shilly Got it ! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Shilly So I'm iterating (in my view) over an instance variable(declared in my controller), and I need to access data from these instances in a js file. I've passed them as data-attributes because I thought that this was the way to do it. But I realized that having multiple data-attributes might not be the way to go. Do you see any alternatives to this ?

Comment: I'm not a ruby expert, but since it's models are serverside, I would expect any changes to come from the server so I don't completely understand. But in single page apps and such, we just ask the server for a json representation of the data the current view used to render, so that you can have an object or array in memory to manipulate instead of having to query out of the DOM. That does require you to hide the sensitive data in that json file as well, so maybe the server can send some kind of command string instead of the data itself. Any more context what you're hiding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li data-first="<% somedata %>" 
    data-second="<% somedata %>" 
    data-third="<% somedata %>" 
    class="someclass">
</li>
```

Which will be displayed as :

```
<li data-first="" data-second="" data-third="" class="someclass"></li>
```

In `erb` the `<%=` will render the result of the code block in the view whereas `<%` just functions as a code block and will not render it.

If you **need** the data in the view, then you must assume that it will be visible to any users. Thus you need to circumvent that vulnerability through other means.

Comment: You misunderstood the problem.